# Is there a better way to update text in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a better way to update the text value here by the value from the database?

```
@Composable
private fun DisplayShops() {
var shopid by remember { mutableStateOf("")}
SideEffect {
    val value = GlobalScope.async {
        val res = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            getDbData() // this gets the database data
            delay(1000)
            shopid=shop_id// the shop_id is variable defined in the activity and it has the value retrieved from the database
        }
    }
}
Text(text =shopid)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a good solution for 2 reasons:

- the code will run at each recomposition, because you are using `SideEffect`, you probably want to use `LaunchedEffect` instead
- placing your business logic in your composables is not the right solution, makes your composables tightly coupled to your business layer and hard to test

You should consider creating a `ViewModel` that will fetch the data from the database and then expose the value you want to display from the `ViewMOdel` using a `MutableState` object that you can then observe in your composable.

You can read [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) for more details.

Comment: Thanks so much! that worked perfectly well, I don't even need that delay anymore.